# Why PlayFramework only "eclipse" one sub module?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Using Play Framework 2.1.1-RC1, I have a project splitted into multiple modules, like so :

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "Project"
  val appVersion      = "1.0"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
  )

  lazy val common = play.Project(
    appName + "-common", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/common")
  ).settings(
    publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
  )

  lazy val website = play.Project(
    appName + "-website", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/website")
  ).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common).settings(
    requireJs += "app.js",

    publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
  )

  lazy val api = play.Project(
    appName + "-api", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/api")
  ).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common).settings(
    publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
  ).dependsOn(website, api).aggregate(website, api)
}
```

So, when I call `play eclipse`, it should eclipsify all the three sub modules, but instead only compile the first one, do you know why ?

Here's the dump from play :

```
$ /opt/play/2.1.1-RC1/play eclipse
  [info] Loading project definition from /mnt/data/dev/perso/Project/project
  [info] Set current project to Project (in build file:/mnt/data/dev/perso/Project/)
  [info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
  [info] Updating {file:/mnt/data/dev/perso/Project/}Project-common...
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Fin                                                                                [info] Done updating.                                                        
  [info] Compiling 27 Java sources to /mnt/data/dev/perso/Project/modules/common/target/scala-2.10/classes...
  [info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
  [info] Project-common
$
```

Why? Is there any reason ?

If I run the project, everything works fine, each module works correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so, with a great indication from @Stijn from the [Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/0Oq3b3sROBs) of PlayFramework, I found the solution.

Using the [PlayFramework documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1-RC1/IDE), you have two options for building all the sub modules :

**Option 1:**

Going into the `play` console, and then calling `eclipse skip-parents=false` :

```
$ /path/to/playframework/play
[PlayProject] $ eclipse skip-parents=false
```

*Warning!* doing this outside the play console doesn't work :

```
$ /path/to/playframework/play eclipse skip-parents=false
> [error] Not a valid key: skip-parents (similar: ivy-paths)
> [error] skip-parents=false
```

**Option 2:**

Modifying Build.scala :

```
import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.EclipsePlugin.EclipseKeys

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  override def settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
      EclipseKeys.skipParents in ThisBuild := false
  )

  ...

}
```

Don't forget to import EclipseKeys!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just have this when I use the .dependsOn(xy).aggregate(xy)

Answer (score 2):

doing this outside the play console will work if you write:

```
play "eclipse skip-parents=false"
```